# Sylius/rbac-bundle for existing Symfony2 application

Tags: symfony, acl, sylius

I have to implement sylius/rbac-bundle for ACL in existing Symfony2 application.
I have seen I suppose everything that can be googled out about the topic, but nowhere to see an example.

How can I do that? 
I have User entity. What do I do with it now by using this new bundle?

I installed sylius/rbac-bundle with all required dependencies.

```
"sylius/resource": "0.14.*@dev",
"sylius/translation": "0.14.*@dev",
"sylius/translation-bundle": "0.14.*@dev",
"sylius/storage": "0.14.*@dev",
"sylius/resource-bundle": "0.14.*@dev",
"sylius/rbac": "0.14.*@dev",
"sylius/rbac-bundle": "0.14.*@dev"
```

and added this to AppKernel:

```
new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle(),
new Sylius\Bundle\TranslationBundle\SyliusTranslationBundle(),
new Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\SyliusResourceBundle(),
new Sylius\Bundle\RbacBundle\SyliusRbacBundle(),
```

I see there is a console command:

```
sylius:rbac:initialize
```

but now the `php app/console` results in following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
The service "sylius.translatable.listener" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "sylius.translation.mapping". 
Did you mean one of these: "sylius.translation.default.mapping", "sylius_translation.driver"?
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: The authors updated official docs: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusRbacBundle/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to also configure Sylius TranslationBundle

```
sylius_translation:
    default_mapping:
        translatable:
            field: translations
            currentLocale: currentLocale
            fallbackLocale: fallbackLocale
        translation:
            field: translatable
            locale: locale
```

Comment: Do I really need TranslationBundle? Thank you Adam. I was thinking, whats the point of being a bundle if it can't be used on its own? :)

Comment: Perhaps I should install the whole Sylius or it's core, with rbac-bundle which I actually need.

Comment: In a way, you're right. At the very least these could be the default settings for TranslationBundle (I might submit a patch to do so). However as Sylius gets more decoupled, it's likely that some high-level packages (Rbac) will have many dependencies on low-level ones (Translation, Resource). As for installing the whole Sylius, that's what I've had to do as well ;)